# separar y re direccionar el login y register en la platilla php

Tags: php, .htaccess

estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion web, con login, registarse y demas secciones, el problema que tengo y pregunto es como puedo incluir el register en esta plantilla, ya que cuando lo incluyo en cualquier parte sale el login y el register en la misma pagina, tengo todas las vistas en una misma carpeta, los controladores en otros y la platilla que tiene todo lo visual donde incluyo las vistas.

```html
  

 
  <?php



     if(isset($_SESSION['iniciarSesion'])&&$_SESSION['iniciarSesion']=="ok"){
echo '<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">';
echo '<div class="wrapper">';
         
      include "Vistas/modulos/cabezote.php";
    include "Vistas/modulos/menu.php";
    
   
 
    
    if(isset($_GET['ruta'])){
      if($_GET['ruta']=="inicio"||
        $_GET['ruta']=="AdministrarUsuarios"||
          $_GET['ruta']=="CambiarContrasena"||
            $_GET['ruta']=="DatosMedicamentos"||
              $_GET['ruta']=="RegistrarMedicamentos"||
                $_GET['ruta']=="RegistroMedicamentos"||
                  $_GET['ruta']=="Reportes"||
                    $_GET['ruta']=="StockMedicamentos"||
                     $_GET['ruta']=="salir"){

        include "Vistas/modulos/".$_GET['ruta'].".php";

      }else{
        include"Vistas/modulos/404.php";
      }
      }else{
        include"Vistas/modulos/inicio.php";

      }
    include "Vistas/modulos/footer.php";

  }else{
    echo '<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed login-page">';
    include "Vistas/modulos/login.php";
   
  }
    
    
  ?>
```

[image: como ven salen superpuestas en la misma pagina]

codigo del login

```html
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="../../index2.html"><b>Medi</b>Fast</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body login-card-body">
      <p class="login-box-msg">Inicia Sesion para continuar</p>

      <form  method="post">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese usuario" name="ingUsuario">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-user-md"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="ingPassword">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       
           
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-100">
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Accerder</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>

        <?php

        $login = new ControladorUsuarios();
        $login -> ctrIngresar();
        ?>
      </form>

      <p class="mx-auto">
        <a style="color:#df5b54" href="register" class="text-center" color="red">¿No tienes una cuenta?, Registrate.</a>

      </p>

    <!-- /.login-card-body -->
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

codigo del register

```html
<div class="register-box">
  <div class="register-logo">
    <img style="margin-top:-9px" src="../img/logop.png" alt="MediFast" height="73">        <b>Medi</b>Fast
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body register-card-body">
      <p class="login-box-msg">Registrate en MediFast</p>

      <form action="../../index.html" method="post">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

       <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-id-card"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-phone-alt"></span>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repetir password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Registrarse</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>

      </form>


      <a style="color:#df5b54" href="login" class="text-center">¿Ya estas registrado?, Inicia Sesion para continuar.</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-box -->
  </div><!-- /.card -->
</div>
```

por cierto utilizo un htacces para redireccionar y ocultar la extencion.php

```html
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

Comment: Quieres mostrar ambos en la misma página pero solo mostrar el de registro si la persona no esta registrada verdad?

Comment: Exactamente, para que al darle no tienes una cuenta?, Regístrate. Te mandé a registro y si ya tiene cuenta te mandé a inicio pero sale asi

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con javascript

Comment: Si, pero de qué forma?

Comment: Te voy a dar una explicación breve pero si quieres añado una respuesta, al formulario de registro ocultalo y si el usuario no tiene cuenta le dará click a *no tienes una cuenta?* capturas el evento con js y muestras el formulario

Comment: Me agradaría la respuesta para hacerme una mejor idea, igual buscaré y trataré de crearla, gracias

Comment: el codigo del login y del registro esta en la misma pagina verdad?, por eso se muestran los dos,¿no? , en base a eso elaboro la respuesta

Comment: no, estan en dos paginas diferentes, donde la incluyo en platilla donde esta todos los plugins y css, me sale asi por el if, no se donde incluir el registro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo haría seria dividirlos por `GET` acá va un ejemplo.

```
<?php
  if($_GET["ruta"] == 'registro'){
?>
ACA CODIGO DE REGISTRO
<?php
  }
  if($_GET["ruta"] == 'login'){
?>
ACA CODIGO DE LOGIN
<?php
  }
?>
```

y llamarlos usando httaccess

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ingresar/([a-zA-Z-]+|)$ ingresar.php?ruta=$1 [L]
```

entonces la url te quedaría ingresar/registro si queres registrarte y ingresar/login si deseas loguearte.

espero que te sirva de ayuda, cualquier cosa me avisas!

Comment: hola muchas gracias, segui tu consejo e ingrese el formulario de registro en el mismo login pero dentro de un modal y se me soluciono el problema muchas gracias por la ayuda